“Die Daily” or “die every day”
What is the best translation for “die daily” or “die every day”
“Die” as in: remember to suffer daily (like Jesus says “pick up your cross and follow me”

Seneca the Younger has a couple of places in the Epistulae morales ad Lucilium where he expresses the idea of dying every day by using a form of the verb morior plus the adverb cotidie. However, he's referring to the notion that every day that passes takes a little bit off the lifespan that remains to us, bringing us closer to death; there's no hint at all of 'remember[ing] to suffer daily.' Still, if you want to adopt his expression and use it with more connotative than denotative force, you could say cotidie morere.

"Are you referring to, "qui intellegat se cotidie mori," = "He who may understand that every day he is dying,"? Was Seneca a joy to know?

If you're going for a Christian angle, here are two options:

Beatus, qui horam mortis suae semper ante oculos habet et ad moriendum quotidie se disponit. (De Imitatione Christi, I.XXIII)

My translation:

Blessed is he who always has the hour of his death before his eyes and daily prepares himself for dying.

Here also is Saint Paul in 1 Corinthians 15:13:
Greek:

καθ᾽ ἡμέραν ἀποθνήσκω

Latin Vulgate:

Quotidie morior

English:

I die daily.

If you put this in the imperative, it of course yields the same suggestion as @cnread's above: Quotidie morere.

There are many ways to say "every day" in Latin. I am fond of the idiom used in the Psalms, die in diem. So you could translate "die every day" as die in diem moritor.
If the future imperative is too archaic for you, you could simply replace it with the present imperative, die in diem morere.
